# Who was responsible for the decision to play "Live and Let Die" at Trump's visit to a mask factory?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, healthcare, covid-19, rhetoric

Some of the media has been [pointing out](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/may/06/trump-live-and-let-die-mask-factory-video) the irony in that when Trump was visiting a mask factory, the Guns and Roses song ["Live and Let Die"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_and_Let_Die_(song)#Guns_N'_Roses_version) was being  played on loudspeakers. Some [coverage](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/us/trump-tours-mask-factory-as-live-and-let-die-blares-on-speakers-1.4246237) of the event mentions that

> Other songs on the factory playlist featured at recent Trump rallies.

Who decided to play this song while Trump was visiting? I'm guessing it was the company management, but I could be wrong... Given the mention that other songs on the playlist were in common with Trump rallies, was this a joint decision with the Trump campaign and/or the White House perhaps? Are there any details known on how the mask-factory playlist came into being?

Comment: Factory playlist?  Wouldn't that be creating a hostile work environment?  (Irregardless of whether Trump was there or not.)

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  This forum is looking quite ridiculous to me.  The scientific branches of SE seem much better managed.

Comment: I agree with @mbsq. Its a bit peripheral, but a news story about the US president that got world-wide coverage seems to be political to me. If someone staged the incident by putting that song on  while Trump was being filmed then they are engaging in politics. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This would seem to fall into one of two camps. Either trivial or unanswerable. If someone did it deliberately and comes forward it will be picked up world wide like the clip was. If they don't come forwards no one can answer it. So it doesn't seem likely to ever have something worthwhile to add to visitors'  understanding of politics.

Comment: @Jontia: I disagree. One can shed some light on how such "working visits" are arranged.

Comment: Sure it could. But a question asking how factory tours are arranged, how sites are chosen and how choreographed the visit is would do that better. And it still won't tell you who put the CD on.

Comment: "Guns and Roses"?!?!?! It's Sir Paul's song, performed by Wings...